# GWT Exception changes on Client Side

Tags: exception, gwt, serialization

I want to send a exception which are thrown on the server side to the client side. ATM it works partial.

When a method from my `DatabaseServerConnectionImpl` fails, I save the exception, then the client detects (onFailure) that the method has failed and returns the previously saved exception with a further callback.

This exception now contains a message and a stacktrace. The message is the right one, but the stacktrace is wrong. I checked the stack trace on the server side before the return command and it was the right one. For Example (on the server side)  :

```
org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2077)
```

On the client side the exception later looks like :

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.lang.Exception_FieldSerializer.instantiate(Exception_FieldSerializer.java:16) and it has a different length
```

When I create the exception I just set the message and the stacktrace. And afaik the exception is default serialized. The other method on the server side are working without any problems.
Edit : Add some Source Code : 
A example method from DatabaseServerConnectionImpl
The lastexception is a member value !
...

```
try {
        database.doStuff(obj);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Logger.getInstance().log(e); // Logs the Errors
         lastException = new Exception(e.getMessage());
        StackTraceElement[] tmp = new StackTraceElement[e.getStackTrace().length];
        for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
            tmp[i] = e.getStackTrace()[i];
        }
        lastException.setStackTrace(tmp);
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
```

When the asynchronous callback fails on the client side, i call the following method on the server side :

@Override
    public final SerializableException getLatestException() {

```
     return  lastException; 
    }
```

I tried the method above also with an try and catch block , but not exception was caught.

Comment: Can you post some really short sample code ?

Answer (score 0):

The Exception says, that one element of your rpc-dto could not be serialized.

This may be the captured Exception. Has the Exception an parameterless constructor? If not, it cannot be serialized.

I think it is not a good idea to send the complete stcktrace to the client. Is a simple errorcode not enough for your use-case?

Comment: In some cases it's useful to see stacktrace on the client side and you do not always have to open the log file. 
I fixed the problem with creating my own Exception class. It implements Serializable and save the stackTrace as String Array and the normal error code as String.